# How to do double if statement in prolog?

Tags: if-statement, prolog

i'm learning for an exam right now, and asked myself if there is a way to do a doubled if-statement like in Java it's

```
if(foox<bar && boo<far)   
  {
  foobar; 
  }
```

If there is one, how do I do it?

Comment: Yes what's you are asking

Comment: @Wooble: Yes, learning prolog. I assume you hint my code example. I forgot to mention it's java.

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years: Could you also tell me, how to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Prolog it would be just something like this (here I mean "procedural" variant, i.e. run `foobar` if conditions are true):

```
... some code before ...
Foox < Bar, 
Boo < Far,
foobar.
```

Comma means "and", and it is "short-circuited" like in most programming languages.

Keep in mind that if the variables are not instantiated or `foobar` is not deterministic, it will backtrack and the behavior may be different from Java code.

"Logic" variant (i.e. foobar is true if the conditions are true):

```
foobar(Foox, Bar, Boo, Far) :-
    Foox < Bar, 
    Boo < Far.
```

Another way to specify "procedural" variant - in "if-then-else" style:

```
( Foox < Bar, Boo < Far ->
    foobar
  ; 
    true % else branch 
)
```